# XA error: XAResource.XAER_NOTA start() failed on resource 'SOADataSource_idm_domain': The XID is not valid

Tags: soa, oim

I came across "

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception  while
>   enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException:  XA error:
>   XAResource.XAER_NOTA start() failed on resource
>   'SOADataSource_idm_domain': The XID is not valid

" exception while analysing the soa request through em console.
Any idea about this exception,how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Fix.

I had faced the issue twice.
For the first time when i encountered this issue,i had to increase the JTA timeout for the failing Data-source from default value to 1200(some greater value),i followed below steps,

```
1. Login to weblogic console
2. Goto Services > JTA
3. Open Configuration > JTA
4. Increase the "Timeout Seconds" value
```

On restarting the managed servers,the issue was solved.
But,Second time(scenarios were different related to soa workflows/composite),the issue was very similar and its resolution was same as above,and that I have already tried.But below solution have saved my time :

```
1. Click DataSources under Service
2. Select the Datasource(you can pick the name from exception),in my case SOADataSource.
3. Go to Configuration > Transaction.
4. Check the checkbox "Set XA Transaction Timeout".
```

Restart the servers targeted to run on this Datasource.

Comment: I have same configuration enabled in weblogic but still getting the same error, any idea where i should check this or what is the pattern of this error?

Comment: As per your comments above, configuration is already available in production weblogic but someime getting the same error ...

Comment: I think the problem in wrong database driver in Weblogic when create new data source